# Javascript working in Safari but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I created a series of simple drop downs that create custom sentences based on what option a user selects. The code takes these inputs and adds them to a sentence framework basically. The code works very well in Safari, doing everything as it should. However, when I run it in Chrome, I receive no output whatsoever. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

I am receiving this error message in Chrome but not in Safari:

> stackoverflow2.htm:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: input6 is not defined
>   
>      at sentence (stackoverflow2.htm:39)
>   
>      at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (stackoverflow2.htm:107)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 <title>Hi</title>

 <style type="text/css">
  table,td,th {margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}
  .display {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
  p {text-align: center;}
  textarea {display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;}
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function sentence() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";// reset
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "block";
    if (document.getElementById("z1").value == "") {
      alert("Year, Make, and Model are needed");
      document.getElementById("z1").focus();}
      else if (document.getElementById("z2").value == "") {
      alert("Mileage is needed");}
      else if (document.getElementById("z3").value == "") {
      alert("Exterior color is needed");}
    else {
      const input1 = document.getElementById("z1").value;
      const input2 = document.getElementById("z2").value;
      const input3 = document.getElementById("z3").value;
      const input4 = document.getElementById("z4").value;
      const input5 = document.getElementById("z10").value;
      if (document.getElementById("z4").value=="okay"){
        const input6 = "It has a few " + input5 + ". ";}
        else {const input6 = "";}


      document.getElementById("s1").value =
        "Up for sale is a " + input1 + " with " + input2 + " miles. It is finished in "
        + input3 + ". It is in " + input4 + " shape. " + input6 + "I have owned this car for six years.";

    }
  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";
  }


  function hide() {
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "none";
  }

      function condition ()
      {
        if (document.getElementById("z4").value == "okay") {
          document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "block";}
          else {
            document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "none";
          }
      }

 </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="hide()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z1" placeholder="Year, Make, Model" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z2" placeholder="Mileage" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z3" placeholder="Exterior Color" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <div onclick="condition()">
          <select name="condition" id="z4"  class="chosen-select">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Condition</option>
            <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
            <option value="good">Good</option>
            <option value="okay">Okay</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="z5">
          <select name="condition" id="z10" class="chosen-select">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Why?</option>
            <option value="scratches">Scratches</option>
            <option value="dents">Dents</option>
            <option value="mechanical issues">Mechanical Issues</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z2" placeholder="Test" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="sentence()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="s1"></textarea>
    <br>

    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="reset()" id="r1">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does Chrome's error console say?

Comment: Says that input6 is not defined but I created a const for it just within an if statement.

Comment: @PhilMotto - Please use the "edit" link to post a copy-and-paste of the error message in the question (in a blockquote).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that code is working in Safari, it's a bug in Safari.

`const` has block scope (like `let`, *un*like `var`). Switching to more conventional indentation and bracing, you have:

```
if (document.getElementById("z4").value == "okay") {
    const input6 = "It has a few " + input5 + ". ";
    // `input6` exists here
} else {
    const input6 = "";
    // Another `input6` exists here
}
// No `input6` exists here

document.getElementById("s1").value =
  "Up for sale is a " + input1 + " with " + input2 + " miles. It is finished in "
  + input3 + ". It is in " + input4 + " shape. " + input6 + "I have owned this car for six years.";
// Error here -------------------------------------^
```

Those `input6` identifiers **only** exist within the blocks they're declared in, not later in the line assigning to `value`.

Instead, you need to declare `input6` *outside* those blocks. You can use the conditional operator to get rid of the blocks entirely:

```
const input6 = document.getElementById("z4").value == "okay"
    ? "It has a few " + input5 + ". "
    : "";
```

or `let` outside the blocks:

```
let input6;
if (document.getElementById("z4").value == "okay") {
    input6 = "It has a few " + input5 + ". ";
} else {
    input6 = "";
}
```

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder, now I am receiving an error message in Safari with the let. I updated the code above.

Comment: @PhilMotto - I've rolled back that edit. FYI, questions on SO are not meant to be moving targets, and editing the question such that the answers no longer make sense isn't okay. It sounds like you must be using a really old version of Safari. You may need to use `var` instead of `let`.

Answer (score 0):

change this code:

```
if (document.getElementById("z4").value=="okay"){
const input6 = "It has a few " + input5 + ". ";
}
else {
const input6 = "";
}
```

to

```
var input6 = "";
if (document.getElementById("z4").value=="okay"){
    input6 = "It has a few " + input5 + ". ";
}
```

Comment: lol. i don't know what framework he is using, probably const means something. just copy paste it.

Comment: @Dongdong - [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is part of modern JavaScript, not a framework.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot something important - that is the problem that the keywords const and let helps us solve in JavaScript. Why you get the error is because const input6 is only available inside the

> > if (document.getElementById("z4").value=="okay"){
> >        .....
> >        }else{
> >           ...
> >         }

blocks. If you used var instead of const or let, your code would have worked though erroneously. So it was good to give you that informative error to make better mind the rules of block scoping. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). So I used let instead and simply change the value upon the outcome of the if statement. 
Please if you need more clarification, let me know

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <title>Hi</title>
<meta name="name" content="content" charset="UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
  table,td,th {margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}
  .display {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
  p {text-align: center;}
  textarea {display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;}
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function sentence() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";// reset
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "block";
    if (document.getElementById("z1").value == "") {
      alert("Year, Make, and Model are needed");
      document.getElementById("z1").focus();}
      else if (document.getElementById("z2").value == "") {
      alert("Mileage is needed");}
      else if (document.getElementById("z3").value == "") {
      alert("Exterior color is needed");}
    else {
      const input1 = document.getElementById("z1").value;
      const input2 = document.getElementById("z2").value;
      const input3 = document.getElementById("z3").value;
      const input4 = document.getElementById("z4").value;
      const input5 = document.getElementById("z10").value;
      let input6 = "";
       // Using const here will result in Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable when you try to assign it a new value
      if (document.getElementById("z4").value=="okay"){
         input6 = "It has a few " + input5 + ". ";}
        else { input6 = "";}


      document.getElementById("s1").value =
        "Up for sale is a " + input1 + " with " + input2 + " miles. It is finished in "
        + input3 + ". It is in " + input4 + " shape. " + input6 + "I have owned this car for six years.";

    }
  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";
  }


  function hide() {
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "none";
  }

      function condition ()
      {
        if (document.getElementById("z4").value == "okay") {
          document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "block";}
          else {
            document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "none";
          }
      }

  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="hide()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z1" placeholder="Year, Make, Model" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z2" placeholder="Mileage" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z3" placeholder="Exterior Color" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <div onclick="condition()">
          <select name="condition" id="z4"  class="chosen-select">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Condition</option>
            <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
            <option value="good">Good</option>
            <option value="okay">Okay</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="z5">
          <select name="condition" id="z10" class="chosen-select">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Why?</option>
            <option value="scratches">Scratches</option>
            <option value="dents">Dents</option>
            <option value="mechanical issues">Mechanical Issues</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z2" placeholder="Test" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="sentence()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="s1"></textarea>
    <br>

    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="reset()" id="r1">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```